# Button over google map not working on Firefox, but working on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-maps, google-chrome, firefox

I have an Angular 6 project with a page with a fullscreen Google Map (With Angular Google Map component) and I put a button over it to go to another page.

The button works just fine on Chrome, but not in Firefox.

**Chrome:**

[image]

**Firefox:**

[image]

This is the HTML

```
<button type="button" [routerLink]="hxpCaptureUrL">
<span class="hb hb-md hb-custom hxp-button spin" disabled>Activar Celda</span></button>

<div class="map">
  <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="3" [styles]="mapStyles" [streetViewControl]="false"
           [minZoom]="2" [zoomControl]="false" class="height-full width-full">
    <agm-marker *ngFor="let hxp of hxps; let i = index" #marker
                [latitude]="hxp.lat"
                [longitude]="hxp.lng"
                [iconUrl]='{"url": hxp.icon,"scaledSize": {"height": 15, "width": 15}}'
                (markerClick)="markerOnClick(modalDialog, hxp, i)">
    </agm-marker>
  </agm-map>
</div>
```

The button is using [this CSS library](http://shariarbd.com/demo/css3-hexagon-buttons/)

This is the CSS

```
.map {
  top: 0px !important;
  left: 0px !important;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* General Button Style */
.hxp-button{
  font-family: 'AndaleMono', Fallback, sans-serif !important;
  position: relative;
  display:block;
  background: transparent;
  line-height:60px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  text-decoration:none;
  top: 35vh;
  margin-left: 10vh;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Have you checked if the buttons work in Firefox?

Comment: Yes, they work on Firefox.